# Tailwind background utility class not working in Next.js(pages router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, background, tailwind-css, conflict

In the github repo below is my portfolio I'm trying to build and one of the pages in the pages directory was the page of the dashboard project and everything was going well until I tried to add a background color of the tailwind utility class "bg-blue-600" to div element wrapping the react-icon rendered conditionally in the buttons.jsx file in the DashboardComponents directory and I thought it was css conflicts that caused this issue to I tried deleting some styles from globals.css and checking the console for any errors or css conflicts and lots of other possible checking actions but to no avail. Although, bg-white applies with no problems but other color do not
take into account that these libraries are included in the project:
chart.js
react-chartjs-2
react-icons
faker
so if these libraries are responsible for the tailwind background issue, please mention the reason and the solution
this is the repo for the project to have a look:
https://github.com/Alharith-Albayati/portfolio.git
Thank you and I hope the best for you

Comment: move `DashboardComponents` to `components` folder so tailwind can recognize it

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!